# Sprite Object is being removed based on Collision when the code states otherwise?

Tags: swift, xcode, collision-detection

```
let playerBulletCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
let meteorCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
```

Player Bullet method

```
func fireBullet(){
    
    let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerBullet")
    bullet.name = "playerBullet"
    bullet.size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
    bullet.position = player.position
    bullet.zPosition = 6
    player.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = 0
    player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = 0
    bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: bullet.size)
    bullet.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    bullet.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    bullet.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = playerBulletCategory
    bullet.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = meteorCategory
    bullet.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = meteorCategory
    self.addChild(bullet)
    
    let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(x: self.size.width + bullet.size.width, duration: 1)
    let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveBullet,deleteBullet])
    bullet.run(bulletSequence)
```

}

meteor method

```
    let Meteor = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Meteor")
    Meteor.setScale(1)
    Meteor.position = startPoint
    Meteor.zPosition = 5
    Meteor.name = "Meteor"
    Meteor.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: Meteor.size.width / 2)
    Meteor.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    Meteor.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
    Meteor.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = meteorCategory
    Meteor.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
    Meteor.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = playerBulletCategory
    
    self.addChild(Meteor)
```

Did-begun if contact detected method

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    
    let Collision:UInt32 = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
    
    if Collision == meteorCategory | playerBulletCategory {
        
        playerBulletCollide(bullet: contact.bodyB.node!)
       
           if(contact.bodyA.node != nil){
           spawnExplosion(spawnPosition: contact.bodyA.node!.position)
           print("contact is done")
       
        }
        
        meteorHealthFunction()
        
        if(meteorHealth == 0){
            
            meteorCollide(Meteor: contact.bodyA.node!)
            print("contact is works")
        }
        
    }
```

when the bullet comes in contact with the meteor, the meteor should be removed but only when bullet makes contact with the meteor 3 times but the meteor gets removed after 1 contact and even after removing the contact code, the meteor still gets removed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does "Node is being removed based on Collision" mean, and what is your definition of physics collision?

Comment: When Bullet and Meteor collide with one another they bullet should be removed

Comment: Physical collision and physical contact are two different physical phenomena.

Comment: Yeah I agree but not sure why the meteor gets removed with though I wrote the code to remove the meteor after the bullet comes into contact with meteor 3 times